# Searching comments

Tags: support, comment, search

While looking over some material concerning "separable differential equations", I remembered a conversation I had  (via comments) with another MSE user and wanted to find said conversation.

I specifically remember him calling referring to "separate and integrate" as the "orangutan method" of solving such equations (hah!). Not surprisingly, searching *orangutan* yields no results.

So is there are way to include comments in the search parameters?

*(Before posting this, I found [the discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29068/differential-equation/29070#29070) with Google's help... is Google the best way to perform such searches?)*

Comment: A good question! A useful feature would be the ability to do a search in our own activity history. I have been here only since early June, and it is already 43 pages.

Comment: @Jyrki, to which history are you referring? I see 7 pages of answers on your profile.

Comment: The history of my 'activity'. Not the history of answers on the 'info'-page. It lists all my answers and revisions and badges as markers only, but the comments are there verbatim.

Comment: Ohhhh. I see what you're talking about. Thanks!

Comment: Using Google with `site:math.stackexchange.com` usually does the job for me.

Comment: I did not know that it is possible to limit a google search to range over a single site only. But I found a promising box in their advanced search -window, and it seems to work. Thanks @t.b. !

Comment: Related: [How to browse or search comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12142)

Answer (score 8):

Stack Exchange's built-in search is limited to questions and answers. Comments are second-class citizens by design; they're not meant to have information with any lasting value, which is why SE developers don't put any effort in making them more searchable.

You can use a web search engine, such as Google. On Google, add `site:math.stackexchange.com` to limit the search to this site (including meta); other search engines (yes, they exist) tend to have a similar capability. For example, [`orangutans site:math.stackexchange.com`](http://www.google.com/search?q=orangutans+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com) finds your comment (and will find this meta thread soon after I post).

If you know who posted the comment, you can look at that user's comment activity (sorted by date). For example, [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7850/the-chaz?tab=activity#page_1-filter_comments) are your recent comments.

If you still can't find the comment you're looking for, you can turn to methods that involve a bit more familiarity with computers, if not outright programming.

The [Stack Exchange API](http://api.math.stackexchange.com/) allows a number of queries. In particular, you can search for [comments within a date range](http://api.math.stackexchange.com/1.1/usage/methods/comments), [comments on a given set of posts](http://api.math.stackexchange.com/1.1/usage/methods/comments-on-posts), or [comments by a given user](http://api.math.stackexchange.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-comments) (optionally restricted to those [addressed to a given user](http://api.math.stackexchange.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-comments-to-user)). You can retrieve up to 100 results per query (specify 100 as the value of the `page` parameter), and use your browser or a text editor's search command on your computer to locate the precise comment you're interested in. For example, the URL `http://api.math.stackexchange.com/1.1/users/7850/comments?pagesize=100` retrieves your 100 most recent comments; the next ones are at `http://api.math.stackexchange.com/1.1/users/7850/comments?pagesize=100&page=2`.

If you don't remember who posted the comment, and it's not a very recent one, then you can turn to the [Stack Exchange data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/). This is a read-only copy of the SE database, updated roughly once a month. Searching it requires knowing some [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) (specifically [Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx)). [Browse existing queries first](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/queries). There is already a query to [search through all users' comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/793/search-all-comments). Note that the search is case-sensitive, so you need to search `Orangutan` or `rangutan`, you won't find your comment by searching `orangutan`. You can use the character `%` to stand for any substring (e.g. a search for `Or%tan` finds many comments including that Orangutans one), and `_` to stand for any one character.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Like it or not, comments at m.se often contain a great deal of value.