# Searching in comments for a specific OP of a question and a word used in comments

Tags: discussion, comment, search, specific-user, comment-replies

I would like to search for my username user122424 and a specific word used in comments that I remember  from reading that comment to get back to it. How can I do that?

Comment: To be clear it was a comment directed at you / about you. Not one you wrote?

Comment: @quid Yes, a comment to my question and not written by me.

Comment: I think you have to use SEDE or a datadump, likely somebody else will provide details. There is no way on-site.

Comment: @quid That's not good. What's SEDE ? Could possibly this feature be added to stackexchange site ?

Comment: @quid I have tried google but it hasn't found what I have remembered to be under my question in the comment.

Comment: IIRC comments are not indexed by Google thus that's expected. SEDE means Stack Exchange Data Explorer. See the answer. // The feaure is unlikely to be added as comments are not considered as relevant.

Comment: @quid I somehow doubt that Google distinguishes between posts and comments in some major way - I guess the Google crawler simply checks what it sees on the page. (I agree that it would not surprise me if some comments might be missed by the crawler, especially in case when there is many comments. And certainly Google is rather suboptimal tool for searching comments.) Just to test is here are some Google searches which clearly find posts based on the comments [dictatorship anarchy](https://www.google.com/search?q=dictatorship+anarchy+site:math.meta.stackexchange.com) or ...

Comment: ... [proviso rubbish](https://www.google.com/search?q=proviso+rubbish+site:math.meta.stackexchange.com), in both cases searching on meta. (I hoped I would be able to find some notable comment or clever pun as an example. But since I wasn't able to recall something like that, I just tried with some random comments - but I chose such comments which contain some distinctive word.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak it seems I misunderstood something in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange API have a [function to return replies to specific user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/mentions-on-users), so it is possible that you could somehow search among replies to you using this. But as I am not really familiar with using the API, I won't be able to suggest details of such method.

As mentioned in the comments, you could use the [SEDE (Data Explorer)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). This was suggested also in older similar posts on this meta such as: [Searching comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3097) or [How to browse or search comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12142). You can also check some posts on Meta Stack Exchange, such as: [How can I search for specific comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23771) pr [Can I search my comments using some keyword(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148066) (There are also a few feature requests about this: [Ability to search comments would be useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183142) or [Add Ability To Search Comments Only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113621). So if you think this would be a useful improvement, you can upvote those.)

Most likely interpretation of your question is that your looking for the words which contain both your username and also a phrase you're searching for. I will also include some other queries. Don't forget to switch to the site where you want to search (all linked queries are for the main site here on Mathematics). You can change the parameters to look for different phrases. (Parameters can be changed directly in the url or in the boxes below the query.)

- You can search for comments containing two different strings, such as [122424 and how](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1259738/comments-containing-the-given-two-keywords?word1=122424&word2=how). Notice that the query is case sensitive. Here is [case insensitive version](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1261689/comments-containing-the-given-two-keywords-case-insensitive?word1=122424&word2=how).
- You can also search for [comments by a specific user containing the given string](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1074444/comments-by-a-specific-users-containing-a-given-word?word=how&userid=122424). Again, here is also a [case insensitive version](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1261690/comments-by-a-specific-users-containing-the-given-word-case-insensitive?word=how&userid=122424). (One of the parameters here is the userid of the user whose comments you want to see. Just in case, I'll include links to [Help with what is my user id and how do I check it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6598) and [What is my user ID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98771))
- And [one more query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1261691/comments-on-my-posts-containing-the-given-phrase-case-insensitive?word=how&userid=122424) for comments containing the given word which were made under a post posted by a given user. (So in this case the userid is for the user who made the post, not the one of the commenter.) And here is a similar query, [restricted just to the questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1262055/comments-on-my-questions-containing-the-given-phrase-case-insensitive?type=1&word=how&userid=122424).
- Query searching for [combination of the given two words](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1262057/comments-on-my-posts-containing-two-given-phrases-case-insensitive?userid=122424&word1=how&word2=can) only under posts by a specific user.

Maybe it is worth pointing out that the queries search for a given *string* which might be a part of a longer word. But you can include [also a space as a part of the string](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1259738/comments-containing-the-given-two-keywords?word1=122424&word2=%20how) you're searching for - so this might help in situation when matches for substring/superstring would cause a problem.

And I will include the usual caveat that the data in SEDE are only updated once a week.

Of course, you can create many other queries - limited basically just by the available data and possibilities of SQL. You can find several examples of such queries in the linked posts.

Comment: [This](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1259738/comments-containing-the-given-two-keywords?word1=122424&word2=how) would be OK for me, but it searches apparently only comments **to me** rather then comments from me and a possible word contained in some other comment. I guess so because all results begin with "@user122424: ".

Comment: @user122424 The query you linked searches for *two specific strings* in comments by *any user.* Since one of the strings is 122424, it is only natural that typically those will be comments mentioning your username. If you use the same query with the parameters [atom and poset](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1259738/comments-containing-the-given-two-keywords?word1=atom&word2=poset), you can see that also one of your comments is among the results.

Comment: Since [you have mentioned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32091/searching-in-comments-for-a-specific-op-of-a-question-and-a-word-used-in-comment#comment142621_32091) that is was comment under your question, perhaps the third query could be useful for you. (The one which searches only among the comments under your posts.)

Comment: You link doesn't work. I remember this was under my question: "[Since user122424 has 3000+ reputations this is not] {possible}" The words in [] may not be precisely as in that comment but the word in {} is exact as in the comment, I believe. The comment I'm searching for is from 6th or 7th month from the year 2020.

Comment: @user122424 I don't really know where is the problem. To the best of my knowledge, this query [should return all comments under your posts containing the string possible](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1261691/comments-on-my-posts-containing-the-given-phrase-case-insensitive?userid=122424&word=possible). Maybe the comment was deleted in the meantime? If the questions is not older than 60 days, you could check whether the question wasn't deleted under "deleted recent questions": [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948).

Comment: @user122424 If you say that the comment was posted in the last two month, you could simply check the most recent comments on your posts - there probably aren't that many in that period. You can look at the [in the responses tab of your profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=comments) or you could [use SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1262077/most-recent-comments-on-my-posts?userid=122424).

Comment: Can I reach also comments of my deleted questions ?

Comment: @user122424 Not through searching. But you can access you deleted questions (or answers) if you still have link to them somewhere. (As you probably know - after all, you've been on the site for quite a long time.) Still, there is some limited search for deleted posts that are at most 60 days old (and full search in your deleted posts at 10k+) - if you followed the link from my previous comment, you saw the details there.

Comment: To include at least one example, you should be able to see this deleted question - since it is your question: [Particular non-accessible category](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3695691). It was posted on May 28 which is less than 60 days - so you should be able to find this question yourself using the "deleted recent question". (And once you reach 10k, then the no longer matters if you want to find your deleted posts.)

Comment: Yes, I can access that question, but can I access also **comments** to it ?

Comment: @user122424 It seems to me that we have digressed from the original question (which was about searching comments) quite a lot. Moreover, when reading some of your comments, it's a bit unclear to me what you're actually asking. Let me suggest that we continue [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2020/7/12) (if needed) - chat is more suitable for longer exchanges.